# Postman Variables not getting reset with new iteration

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to use postman to do data testing on some pagination endpoints. Also, using data file to run iterations. Issue is, variable is not getting reset after iteration is finished.
I am using postman's echo endpoint as POC.

My scenario: I want to run api once. Depending on record count I get, I want to jump to last page, and validate the final page records. For this I am trying to update the pageNumber in tests and then re-running the api with updated values.

Here is the data file that I am using in runner,

> [
> {
> "pageNumber": 0,
> "pageSize": 2
> },
> {
> "pageNumber": 0,
> "pageSize": 5
> },
> {
> "pageNumber": 0,
> "pageSize": 10
> }
> ]

Steps:

1. In postman runner, select data file. This should give 3 iterations.
2. Save response, so we can validate the executions
3. Run Postman

Iteration 1 runs fine. pageNumber value is updated correctly.
Ideally, for iteration 2, pageNumber value should be reset to 0, as that's what I provide from my data file. But postman persists the previously calculated value, and does not update this value.

URL = [https://postman-echo.com/get?pageNumber={{pageNumber}}&pageSize={{pageSize}}&totalRecords=46](https://postman-echo.com/get?pageNumber=%7B%7BpageNumber%7D%7D&pageSize=%7B%7BpageSize%7D%7D&totalRecords=46)

[image]

Below is the execution log from console. Highlighted in red, pageNumber should get updated for new iteration, but it doesn't.

[image]

Could someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here? or if I am missing out something wrt how variable update works with data files.

Comment: There is a checkbox enabled when you run the collection that asks you if you want to store the variable value, does unchecking that option help here?

Comment: @DannyDainton tried that too. But didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Postman variable precedence is like:

local>Data>Environment>Collection>Global

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-scopes

so make sure you are not using any local variables like pm.variables.set in your test for the data variable values as this value will have precedence over data variable values

Answer (score 0):

Further accessing, it got more clear that you are trying to access Postman Runner's dataset in your request.
And initializing postman's local variables for logging purpose only.

To serve this (logging) purpose, it should be stored into js variables rather than postman environment variables.

---

Though, runner dataset can be accessible via `pm.iterationData.get('pageNumber')` as mentioned on [docs](https://blog.postman.com/looping-through-a-data-file-in-the-postman-collection-runner/#using-data-variables-in-scripts).

And can be utilized into **pre-request script** to avoid conflicts between local variables and iteration dataset variables.

```js
let pageNumber = pm.iterationData.get("pageNumber");
pm.variables.set("pageNumber", pageNumber);
```

Comment: Issue starts from 2nd iteration itself. In 2nd iteration, pageNumber should get set as 0, and then requests should get executed. But it takes value of pageNumber from Iteration 1 (previous value is 23). 

When the new iteration starts, postman should set the variable values from the data file, but that's not happening.

Comment: @Anshul I have modified the answer, if it is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I added logging just to show the issue. Adding a pre-request script doesn't help at all, as this will update the variable in each request, even during the same iteration. Every new iteration should take up starting value of variables from data file. But that's not happening. Previous value of pageNumber is getting persisted from iteration 1, and still remains same in iteration 2.